# What's initial velocity of a body launched at an angle to the horizon?

Tags: solution-verification, kinematics

I'm trying to throw a projectile at an angle to the horizon. The projectile using its free fall acceleration should fall onto the target. Target height is different. The source is lower than the target. Projectile flight trajectory is parabola. Free fall acceleration is constant and equal to 0.125 units per tic. This unit of measurement is in virtual reality - in game. I'm trying using free fall physics to drop grenade onto target. But both of it are at different heights. Coordinate system origin can be considered to be the source point $S(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ from which grenade is released. We know both points coordinates, free fall acceleration. We can choose the angle to the horizon. We must count the pitch angle between the source and the target. Angle to the horizon will be a value between pitch angle and steep angle. I doubt that I can choose the time during which the projectile would reach the target. It depends on free fall acceleration and angle. 

I have to find the initial velocity of the the projectile that should fall right onto target $T(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. But trajectory highest point (parabola vertex) should raise above target height before crossing it. It's the second parabola point at that height.
Please help me to solve it. Analyze and correct me if I'm wrong:
Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/APnAd.png
$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$,
Source $S(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, target $T(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, Pitch from source to target $\langle AST = \arctan \bigg(\frac{AT}{SA}\bigg)=\delta$.
$\alpha \in (\delta, 90^\circ)$.
$AT=z_1-z_0$,
$SA=\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2}$,
$SA=l=V_{ox}t=V_0 \cos\alpha t$,
$AT=z=V_{oy}t+\frac{g_zt^2}{2}=V_0 \sin\alpha t+\frac{g_zt^2}{2}$,
I need to find initial speed.
$z_1=V_0\sin\alpha t+\frac{g_yt^2}{2}$,
$V_0=\frac{2z_1-g_zt^2}{2\sin\alpha t}.$
$t=\frac{l}{V_0\cos\alpha}$,
$z_1=V_0\sin\alpha t+\frac{g_zt^2}{2}=\frac{V_0l\sin\alpha}{V_0\cos\alpha}+\frac{g_zl^2}{2V_0^2\cos^2\alpha}=l\tan\alpha+\frac{g_zl^2}{2V_0^2\cos^2\alpha},$
$(z_1-l\tan\alpha)V_0^2=\frac{g_zl^2}{2\cos^2\alpha}$,
$V_0^2=\frac{g_zl^2}{2\cos^2\alpha(z_1-l\tan\alpha)}$,
$V_0=\sqrt{\frac{g_zl^2}{2\cos^2\alpha(z_1-l\tan\alpha)}}$.
Is this $V_0$ will be my actual intial velocity speed? Will the projectile reach the target T when $g=0.125$?

Comment: You have mentioned in your post two different things. throwing a projectile from a location on the ground to hit a target above-ground and dropping a grenade from above to hit a target below. These are two different scenarios and should be handled differently. Which case do you want to solve? Your own answer provides a solution to the former scenario. As USER has pointed out in his/her answer, there is a mistake in your answer, i.e. $AZ=z=V_{oy}t+g_zt^2/2$ is wrong. The correct expression for $AZ$ is $AZ=z=V_{oy}t-g_zt^2/2$.

Comment: Projectile or grenade.. the same body. It has mass. Just I named them differently. Consider it to be grenade. And yes because gravity pulls down the sign should be negative. I'll try to progress equation in my next answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach is correct. However check if you correctly choose the sign of $g_z$. It should be negative, if the axis $z$ is directed oppositely to the gravitation force (what you seems to assume).

Answer (score 0):

$z_1=V_0\sin\alpha t-\frac{g_zt^2}{2}=\frac{V_0l\sin\alpha}{V_0\cos\alpha}-\frac{g_zl^2}{2V_0^2\cos^2\alpha}=l\tan\alpha-\frac{g_zl^2}{2V_0^2\cos^2\alpha},$
$\frac{g_zl^2}{2V_0^2\cos^2\alpha}=l\tan\alpha-z_1,$
$V_0^2(l\tan\alpha-z_1)=\frac{g_zl^2}{2\cos^2\alpha},$
$V_0^2=\frac{g_zl^2}{2\cos^2\alpha(l\tan\alpha-z_1)},$
$V_0=\sqrt{\frac{g_zl^2}{2\cos^2\alpha(l\tan\alpha-z_1)}}.$
Is the formula valid when the place from which you release grenade is higher than the target?

Comment: $V_0$ depends on the height of the grenade's releasing point in space. I don't see it in your answer. Would you like to try again or do you want me to post my answer?

Comment: Post your answer.

Comment: Thank you YNK and user. I have managed to do this and to check it. Formula works perfectly. I have written an algorithm in Classic Doom script. Ballistic attack works perfectly using this my derived expression from Kinematics formula. 
Here is the video that shows the result: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SiY0LwFBKQ
This can be considered to be the prove. I have calculated initial velocity and threw grenade at target. It dropped right onto targets coordinates.